# Grab website title and transform umlauts

Tags: php, encoding

I use a small snippet to grab the innertext of `<title>` to get the title of a website, which works pretty well.
But there is a problem with umlauts and other html characters. First I tried using `htmlentities()`, but since there are various ways how websites embed umlauts, it's getting pretty complicated.

E.g. in modern browsers it's ok to write them as plaintext in the source code lik `ä ö ü`, but I want to use them as html entities `&auml; &ouml; &uuml;` to support older browser as well.

So, the real problem is, when both is mixed like this title here (source code) `Pläne: Alkoholverbot für 18-Jährige? &gt; Online Zeitung`.

When I try to use `htmlentities()` the result is `Pl&auml;ne: Alkoholverbot f&uuml;r 18-J&auml;hrige? &amp;gt; Online Zeitung`. Everything is transformed fine, except "**>**" which becomes `&amp;gt;`.

Do I have to use a `str_replace()` method or is there any other best practice to deal with mixed html entities?

Thx

Comment: "to support older browser as well" — those entities have been in HTML since 1997. Why do you want to support browsers that old? **Nobody** uses them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First decode all entities to their Unicode representation with `html_entity_decode()`, then pass the string to `htmlentities()` to re-encode all of them again.